# Table restore from backup in existing database in innodb mysql environment

Tags: mysql, innodb, restore

If innodb database is same, and I need to restore table from previous backup, is it ok to copy paste ibd.frm file or do I need to restore separately and then import it?

Answer (score 0):

NO.  If all you have is files, not a mysqldump, then it is "all or none" for InnoDB.

You could create another MySQL instance (on the same machine or different), mysqldump the one table, then reload it.